# Why core refracted phases like SKS polarise vertically when P to S conversion happens in the Core-Mantle boundary?

Tags: seismology

While working on investigation of seismic anisotropy I came to know that core refracted phases like SKS or SKKS polarise vertically when P to S conversion happens in the Core-Mantle boundary. Why is the S wave in this case always polarised vertically ? Can we get horizontally polarised S wave in this scenario ?